# Django - extended user model not saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-registration

I'm having trouble attempting to save data from my extended user model.

**model.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
"""
The 'user' field creates a link between the django-registration-redux's
default user and allows it to be extended through this model.
"""
user = models.OneToOneField(User)

# Person attributes
address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
town = models.CharField(max_length=50)
postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

# Meta contains information about the class which is not a field.
class Meta:
    abstract = True


class Customer(Person):

# No extra attributes required for Customer.

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username


class Staff(Person):

# Staff attributes
job_role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
medical_contact = models.CharField(max_length=50)
nation_insurance = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserProfileForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
address = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
town = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
postcode = forms.CharField(max_length=7)
phone_no = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**regbackend.py**

```
class CustomRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
form_class = UserProfileForm

def register(self, form_class):
    new_user = super(CustomRegistrationView, self).register(form_class)
    user_profile = Customer()
    user_profile.user = new_user
    user_profile.address = form_class.cleaned_data['address']
    user_profile.town = form_class.cleaned_data['town']
    user_profile.postcode = form_class.cleaned_data['postcode']
    user_profile.phone_no = form_class.cleaned_data['phone_no']
    user_profile.save()

    return user_profile
```

So I need to save attributes of Customer through the registration form which is in the django-registration-redux app. However with my current code it will only save "User" attributes. When I attempted to change the forms model to "Customer" it won't save "User" attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because User is a OnetoOnefield, so you need to create the user, save it and then add it to your Customer object and save it.

You need to do something like that in your forms.py, redefine the save method:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = user.super(UserProfileForm, self).save()
    customer = Customer(user=user)
    customer.save()
```

Don't juste copy paste, it's just you to know you have first to register the user, and then add it to your new object, add the other fields, and save it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have it now so that it does in fact create an instance of Customer which is great, still doesn't actually save the data though. Also I know that the two password fields are called 'password1' and 'password2' but create_inactive_user throws a KeyError asking for 'password'. Thanks again.